# Python ModuleNotFoundError even after appending it

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-module

I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`, while I already included its location:

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file
from io import BytesIO
import re
import json
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64decode
import os
import mysql.connector
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/master/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
```

I am using `python3`.

```
python3 -m site --user-site
/home/master/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Any advise?

Comment: Your code seems to fail after the first line. You should append additional paths before importing the module.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and move the sys.path.append before you try and import modules? (Not before the sys import though)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include it's location, make sure the pandas lib is installed.
Use this command: `pip show pandas`

Answer (score 0):

You should first append the path, then import

```
sys.path.append("/home/master/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file
from io import BytesIO
import re
import json
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64decode
import os
import mysql.connector
import sys
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a few things in this situation.

1. Don't use `sys.append` for importing a library which can be easily installed using pip/pip3.
2. In the above code example you gave, to solve it you need to add the `sys.append` statement in the first line.

I will also recommend you to use `pip install pandas`. If that is not working, you need to find the reason.

Some possible reasons might be:

The Python version and the pip associated with the python version on your system might not be the same. So when you install any package using `pip` it is getting installed for a different version of python and vise-versa.